# How to FOR LOOP every column name in R and turn them to separate dataframes?

Tags: r

I have a csv called stats with 4 columns, Accepted.Items, A, B, C.

Accepted.Items has rows with regular items: Soda can, banana, orange

While columns A,B and C contain either values 'NA' or 'Yellow'

I want to filter values with 'Yellow' for each A, B and C column and create separate data frames for each of them.

```
for (i in colnames(stats)) {
  z <- stats[stats$i == "Yellow",]
  z <- data.frame(z$Accepted.Items, z$i)
  print(z)
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend putting your data frames in a `list`, i.e., `my_list = list; for(name in c("A", "B", "C")) list[[name]] = stats[stats[[name]] == "Yellow", c("Accepted.Items", name)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a column like that, you have to do this instead:

```
# Wrong
data$i 

# Right
data[i]
```